# Show that these two Eigenvalues are positive

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> > In the course of a rather long calculation, I got two Eigenvalues, namely
> >     $$
> > \lambda_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}(2+x^2+u\pm\sqrt{u^2-2ux^2+x^4+4x^2}).
> > $$
> >     I have to show, that these two Eigenvalues are positive. (Here x is out of a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ is a non-negative function.)

Could you please help me to show, tha $\lambda_{1,2}$ are positive? I do not have an idea, how to show that.

Comment: Expression $u^2-2ux^2+x^4$ is factorable as a prefect square. How is that for a start?

Comment: What do you mean with prefect square?

Comment: I mean $(u-x^2)^2$

Comment: Please give us the characteristical polynomial;  I'm too tired to reconstruct it.

Comment: Ok, then I have $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2}(2+x^2+u\pm\sqrt{(u-x^2)^2+4x^2})$. That says me that $\lambda_1=\frac{1}{2}(2+x^2+u+\sqrt{(u-x^2)^2+4x^2})$ is positive, right? Whats with $\lambda_2$?

Comment: @Michael Hoppe The characteristical polynomial is $\lambda^2+(-2-x^2-u)\lambda+1+u+ux^2=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just show that $2+x^2+u > \sqrt{u^2-2ux^2+x^4+4x^2}$
$$\iff (2+x^2+u)^2 > u^2-2ux^2+x^4+4x^2$$
$$\iff 4+4 u+u^2+4 x^2+2 u x^2+x^4 > u^2 - 2 ux^2 + x^4 + 4 x^2$$
$$\iff 4 + 4 u + 4 u x^2 > 0$$

which is true as $u \ge 0$.